# Put the values from database inside a '$string'

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php


$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '1234fedf';
$dbDatabase = 'smsmobile';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

$sql = "SELECT destinationaddress FROM reporting";
//print $sql;

$queryRes1 = mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryRes1))
{
$destinationaddress[] = $rows['destinationaddress']; 

}



$phones = $destinationaddress;


$sqlprefix = "SELECT country,prefix FROM countrycodes";
//print $sqlprefix;

$queryprefix = mysql_query($sqlprefix);

while($data=mysql_fetch_array($queryprefix))
{
$countryarray[] = $data['country']; 
$prefixarry[] = $data['prefix']; 
}
$countryname = implode(',',$countryarray); 
//print $countryname;
$prfixname = implode(',',$prefixarry);
//print $prfix;


$countrycode = $countryname;
$prfix = $prfixname;

foreach($countryname as $key => $value){
$result[] = 'country : '.$value.' prefix:'.$prfix[$key];
}

$allstring = implode(',',  $result);
print_r( $allstring );


    ?>
```

Comment: So you put the prefix in an array.. Then you create a string.. Explode it like hell.. And then you want to have the originel prefix array printed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example your array have some data. You can `implode` array in string, see below

```
$countryarray = array('Pakistan',  'India');
$prefixarry = array(971,  43);

$countrycode = $countryarray;
$prfix = $prefixarry;

foreach($countryarray as $key => $value){
$result[] = 'country : '.$value.' prefix:'.$prfix[$key];
}

$allstring = implode(',',  $result);
print_r( $allstring );
```

Result:

```
country : Pakistan prefix:971,country : India prefix:43
```

Comment: try to explain what should be indicated in the end? Which line has errors? Result of string? (in print_r i lose $ edit pls)

Comment: i am getting like this Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\var\test\test2.php on line 46   Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\wamp\www\var\test\test2.php on line 50   Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\var\test\test2.php on line 50 please see my edited code

Comment: Delete next line `$countryname = implode(',',$countryarray);` and `$prfixname = implode(',',$prefixarry);` and  change line with `$countrycode = $countryname;$prfix = $prfixname;` to `$countrycode = $countryarray; $prfix = $prefixarry;`

Comment: but i am faceing an another issue ,data is not looping throe each values

Answer (score 0):

to convert array in a string u first of all implode u'r result array into string
    $countrycode = implode(',',$countryarray);
    $prfix = implode(',',$prefixarry);

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: i tried your code but i am getting an error Array ( [$prfix] => $countrycode )  Notice: Undefined variable: country in C:\wamp\www\var\test\test2.php on line 76 please see my eited code

Comment: define Country with $country and always make habit of defining array variables to $arrName = array(); and if u are using class the define variable with var varName